# Adding to a HashMap which its Value part is another HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

Sorry if this is a noob question, but I am scratching my head how to add values to the following map inside a for loop:

```
private void filterSnakes() {
    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>> mapSnakes
            = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>>();

    int coutner = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < mGameAssets.length; i++)
    {
        if(mGameAssets[i].getAssetType().isSnake()){ //check if the asset is snake
             mapSnakes.put(++coutner, i,mGameAssets[i].getDamage() );
        }
    }
}
```

I mean how can I put a new entry in the `mapSnakes`, the key part is ok but how about the Value part which itself is a Map?

Comment: Is there any reason for using a hashmap instead of an array if you will use incremental numbers to index it?

Comment: @fejese Just ease of access to the content I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to separate this into two steps:

1. Create the map you want to insert.
2. Insert it into `mapSnakes`.

Like this:

```
if(mGameAssets[i].getAssetType().isSnake()){ //check if the asset is snake
    // Step 1
    Map<Integer,Integer> assetMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    assetMap.put(i, mGameAssets[i].getDamage());
    // Step 2
    mapSnakes.put(++coutner, assetMap);
}
```

Although your design looks a little odd, are you sure this is what you want to be doing?

---

Responding to your comment, you say you want to know two things:

- How many snakes are in `mGameAsset`.
- What indices they are and what their damage is.

You could use a single map for that, a map that maps indices to the snake itself, e.g. assuming your assets are of class `Asset`:

```
private void filterSnakes () {

    // maps asset index => snake
    Map<Integer,Asset> snakes = new HashMap<Integer,Asset>(); 

    // find all the snakes:
    for (int i = 0; i < mGameAssets.length; ++ i) {
        if (mGameAssets[i].getAssetType().isSnake())
            snakes.put(i, mGameAssets[i]);
    }

    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    // now we can process their indices and damage, for example:
    for (Map.Entry<Integer,Asset> snakeEntry : snakes.entrySet()) {
        int index = snakeEntry.getKey();
        int damage = snakeEntry.getValue().getDamage();
        System.out.println("Snake at " + index + " damage is " + damage);
    }

    // and we can find the number of snakes too:
    int snakeCount = snakes.size();
    System.out.println("There are " + snakeCount + " snakes.");

    // bonus: we can even just get a generic collection of the snakes:
    Collection<Asset> snakesOnly = snakes.values();

}
```

Use a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) if you want to preserve insertion order instead.

Another option is to use an `ArrayList` or some other `List` instead of a `Map`; if you do that you'll have to make some small class that can hold an index and a snake (similar to a `Map.Entry<Integer,Asset>`, then you can create one of those small classes for each snake entry and maintain a `List` of those. A bit more work but has the advantage of not having the overhead of a map (which may or may not matter to you).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. About the design, well I want to know how many snakes are in the `mGameAsset` array, and what is theire index in the array and the damage they have. can you suggest something better?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create or fetch the nested map first:

```
++counter;
if (!mapSnakes.containsKey(counter)) {
  mapSnakes.put(counter, new HashMap<Integer, Integer>());
}

mapSnakes.get(counter).put(i,mGameAssets[i].getDamage());
```

In the above code you create the nested map if it does not exist. Next you get the map with `mapSnakes.get(counter)` and add stuff to the nested map.

Comment: This is a good general strategy, although in the OP's example `mapSnakes` is created new and is empty and `i` never repeats;  `containsKey()` will always be false and "fetch/create" will always be "create".

Comment: @JasonC yup, good catch. I just went for a general approach where you have to put several values into a nested map without a specific order of keys

Answer (score 2):

You have declared the map as mapping from an integer to a Map.  Therefore

```
    mapSnakes.put(++counter, i,mGameAssets[i].getDamage() );
```

needs to be something like this:

```
    Map<Integer, Integer> submap = ...
    mapSnakes.put(++counter, submap);
```

... or possibly something like @dimoniy's answer.  (It is not clear, because you don't actually specify *how* you want the data structure to be initialized.  I could guess, but I'm not playing that game this morning.)

---

The other points to be made are:

- This looks like a poor OO design.  Maps of maps of basic types etcetera in Java has "code smell".  Usually it means that you should have defined some application classes.
- Maps are rather expensive data structures, both in memory usage and in time.  And whenever you have to use `Integer` rather `int`, you incur overheads due to boxing and unboxing.